# How can remove empty Array in scala

Tags: arrays, scala, apache-spark

```
input: (Array[Int],Array[Int])

 ex) (Array(1),Array(2)), (Array(),Array()), (Array(4),Array(8)), ...
```

How can I remove empty Array?

expected Output is

```
 ex) (Array(1),Array(2)), (Array(4),Array(8))...
```

Answer (score 2):

You can just use `filter`. If you have a list:

```
val lst = List((Array(1),Array(2)), (Array(),Array()), (Array(4),Array(8)))

lst.filterNot{ case (x, y) => x.isEmpty && y.isEmpty }
// res58: List[(Array[_ <: Int], Array[_ <: Int])] = List((Array(1),Array(2)), (Array(4),Array(8)))
```

If you have a RDD:

```
val rdd = sc.parallelize(lst)
// rdd: org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[(Array[_ <: Int], Array[_ <: Int])] = ParallelCollectionRDD[44] at parallelize at <console>:27

rdd.filter{ case (x, y) => ! (x.isEmpty && y.isEmpty) }.collect
// res60: Array[(Array[_ <: Int], Array[_ <: Int])] = Array((Array(1),Array(2)), (Array(4),Array(8)))
```